# Intellij IDEA community can't compile Chinese characters instead it displays "?" Question marks

Tags: java, intellij-idea

System.out.print("你好");

---

output:
??

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Was the source file saved using e.g., UTF-8? Did you compile with e.g., `-encoding UTF-8`? Can your terminal handle Chinese characters?

Comment: yes it was compiles with -encoding UTF-8 but how can I check if it can handle Chinese characters

Comment: Good question. I can get my terminal to display `你好` just fine (e.g., with `echo`), but cannot get it to work when Java prints out the characters...

Comment: Does the Chinese text appear properly in the code editor of IntelliJ? Have you read the documentation page [on encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html)?

Comment: Works in Java 12 [on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/oifbup).

Comment: @BasilBourque my old laptop was able to display chinese characters after installing
edit - it replaces the chinese text with question marks (?)

Comment: It seems that it depends on the JDK version you're using. [Here](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) with JDK 11+ it works fine and `Charset.defaultCharset()` returns `UTF-8`, with older JDKs it does not work (errors with question marks) and the `defaultCharset` method returns `US-ASCII`.

Comment: @Jonarz I am using JDK 18 I've tried downloading JDK 17 but it was still showing question marks in place of the chinese characters

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue of IntelliJ IDEA:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006/Running-the-Java-project-by-using-the-JDK-18-prints-the-garbled-characters-in-console-when-try-printing-the-non-ASCII-characters

Try the workaround from the issue description:

> Click Run | Edit configurations, add the -Dfile.encoding=<your_system_default_encoding> (example: -Dfile.encoding=gbk in Chinese encoding) in this application's VM options.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but even in JDK 17 it was showing the question marks, and I've tried this solution, but it didn't solve the problem, and it displays regular question marks like this "?" and not like this �